# Ajax stop working if loaded by infinite scrolling in laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am learning ajax and jquery now, i currently develop a page which user can like/dislike post, and the all the post will display by loaded with infinite scroll, by default each time will load 5 post, but the problem is if the post is loaded by infinite scroll then the ajax button will stop working. After i doing some research and i know that is because the function is not loaded. But i cannot found the solution for that, can someone help me here?

This is my ajax button function

```
$('.agree').on('click',function(event){
{
    event.preventDefault();
    postId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset['postid'];
    var isAgree=event.target.previousElementSibling== null;
    $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:urlAgree,
        data:{ isAgree: isAgree,postId:postId,_token:token}
    })
        .done(function() {
            event.target.innerText = isAgree ? event.target.innerText == 'Agree' ? 'You agree this post' : 'Agree' : event.target.innerText == 'Disagree' ? 'You disagree this post' : 'Disagree';
            if (isAgree) {
                event.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = 'Disagree';
            } else {
                event.target.previousElementSibling.innerText = 'Agree';
            }
        });

}
```

});

Here is the infinite scroll function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(fetchPosts);

function fetchPosts() {

    var page = $('.endless-pagination').data('next-page');

    if(page !== null && page !== "") {

        clearTimeout( $.data( this, "scrollCheck" ) );

        $.data( this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function() {
            var scroll_position_for_posts_load = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() + 100;

            if(scroll_position_for_posts_load >= $(document).height()) {
                $.get(page, function(data){
                    $('.posts').append(data.posts);
                    $('.endless-pagination').data('next-page', data.next_page);
                })

            }
        }, 350))

    }
}
```

});

Is there any possible way to combine both function together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delegate your click event

```
$('.posts').on('click','.agree',function(event){
```

Comment: thank you it work!!!!!!!! never though that is so easy to do that, thank you again for your contribution.